# How to do a simple mathematical operation on all lines of a specific column?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a text file named nvt.gro. I want to add 0.5 (+0.5) on all the lines of the last column:

my file is as below:

GRM in vacuum

192700

```
1GRM     C1    1  17.188   0.311  13.994 -0.5971  0.0204 -0.0724
1GRM     C2    2   0.094   0.383   0.005  0.4831 -0.8709 -0.2204
1GRM     C3    3   0.091   0.524   0.008 -0.7098  0.3449 -0.3952
1GRM     C4    4  17.185   0.596   0.007 -0.4066 -0.4079  0.1701
2GRM     C1    5  17.187   0.738   0.016  0.1844 -0.5441 -0.4893
2GRM     C2    6   0.090   0.815   0.011  1.1631 -0.2289 -0.8340
2GRM     C3    7   0.091   0.957   0.014 -0.4473 -0.2423 -0.3223
2GRM     C4    8  17.184   1.028   0.009 -0.4822  0.0086 -0.4791
3GRM     C1    9  17.189   1.171   0.004 -0.0345 -0.8207 -0.6602
3GRM     C2   10   0.095   1.243   0.001  0.1033  0.4238 -0.8983
3GRM     C3   11   0.093   1.384  13.990 -0.0426 -0.1083 -0.8554
3GRM     C4   12  17.182   1.447  13.983 -0.2814 -0.0363 -0.9146
4GRM     C1   13  17.187   1.590  13.974  0.7722  0.4317 -0.4379
4GRM     C2   14   0.092   1.664  13.974 -0.5701  0.2915 -0.3098
4GRM     C3   15   0.095   1.806  13.967  0.4572  0.1368  0.1921
4GRM     C4   16  17.184   1.871  13.967 -0.0747 -0.5492 -0.1254
5GRM     C1   17  17.181   2.013  13.968  0.3071  0.9864 -0.8679
```

I have tried the solution suggested by αғsнιη, the command is:

```
    awk -F'( )' '{ $NF+=0.5 }1' infile > temp_file && mv temp_file infile
```

The original file is as below:

```
  1GRM       C1      1   0.061   0.071   0.001  0.1992  0.0527  0.1652
  1GRM       C2      2   0.184   0.142   0.000  0.0664  0.2913  0.0420
  1GRM       C3      3   0.184   0.284  13.999 -0.2570  0.2834 -0.1888
  1GRM       C4      4   0.061   0.355  13.997 -0.3396  0.1473 -0.2525
  2GRM       C1      5   0.061   0.497  13.992  0.2583  0.1408 -0.0812
  2GRM       C2      6   0.184   0.568  13.988  0.2013  0.2697 -0.6402
  2GRM       C3      7   0.184   0.710  13.982 -0.1735  0.2672 -0.1291
  2GRM       C4      8   0.061   0.781  13.986 -0.0882  0.4033 -0.3202
  3GRM       C1      9   0.061   0.923  13.990 -0.5866  0.4135  0.1416
  3GRM       C2     10   0.184   0.994  13.991 -0.3780  0.0186  0.0961
```

the output is as below:

```
  1GRM       C1      1   0.061   0.071   0.001  0.1992  0.0527  0.6652
  1GRM       C2      2   0.184   0.142   0.000  0.0664  0.2913  0.542
  1GRM       C3      3   0.184   0.284  13.999 -0.2570  0.2834 0.3112
  1GRM       C4      4   0.061   0.355  13.997 -0.3396  0.1473 0.2475
  2GRM       C1      5   0.061   0.497  13.992  0.2583  0.1408 0.4188
  2GRM       C2      6   0.184   0.568  13.988  0.2013  0.2697 -0.1402
  2GRM       C3      7   0.184   0.710  13.982 -0.1735  0.2672 0.3709
  2GRM       C4      8   0.061   0.781  13.986 -0.0882  0.4033 0.1798
  3GRM       C1      9   0.061   0.923  13.990 -0.5866  0.4135  0.6416
```

there is a problem in the alignment of the last column, how can I solve it please ?

Comment: is this some student homework? see https://askubuntu.com/questions/312816/awk-programming-changing-a-field-value-conditionally

Comment: No it is not. I am trying to write a script to automate a simulation process and this one step in the middle. I think the link you provided is about conditional command. mine is not like that. I need to add 0.5 in the last column in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply you can use:

```
awk '{ $NF+=0.5; print }' infile
```

or just:

```
awk '{ $NF+=0.5 }1' infile
```

to keep the columns indentation intact, use:

```
awk -F'( )' '{ $NF+=0.5 }1' infile
```

In `awk`, the `NF` is referring total number of fields in a line, so NF also would be the last field number and if it prepended with `$` operator it will take the value of that field, then `$NF` would be the value of last field or column. the numbers *$1, $2, $3, $4, …*  are value of field *#1, #2, #3, #4, …* respectively.

to save the modification in-place, GNU awk has `-i inplace` option to do it like:

```
gawk -i inplace -F'( )' '{ $NF+=0.5 }1' infile
```

if in your awk it doesn't recognize that, save the output to temp file then rename it with original, like:

```
awk -F'( )' '{ $NF+=0.5 }1' infile > temp_file && mv temp_file infile
```

---

**Update:**

```
awk -F'( )' '{
    x=($NF>0?1:0); $NF+=0.5;
    $NF=sprintf ("%s%.4f", ((x||$NF<0)?"":" "), $NF);
}1' infile > temp_file && mv temp_file infile
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming *nvo.gro* is single tab delimited, (if it's not, run it through `tr -s ' ' '\t'`), and the [**num-utils** package](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/) is installed:

```
paste <(cut -f -8 nvo.gro) <(cut -f 9- nvo.gro | numprocess /+.5/)
```

Comment: But `awk` is probably more succinct.